# HTML Around Group Title

Tags: group

When I create a group, the HTML around the group title isn't parsed. Even if I change those tags, it isn't parsed. Is there some filter I'm unsure of the whole page is running through or is this some sort of bug with   the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module?

[image: HTML around group title]

Comment: Please re-edit your question: Add some more details, where you set the title and why you use HTML, and also use a textual representation of the output instead of an image. This will (1) give us a chance to better understand what you did and (2) let others better find your question when they experience similar issues and use the search function.

Comment: PS.: Also, it would be good to know where and how your group title is printed this way? E.g. is it a view, a block, is it using a custom template, ... - include this information as well.